# Play sound in windows phone error code

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I have a little problem in my code..

```
 private void PlaySound(string name_file_audio)
    {


        using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isf.FileExists(name_file_audio))
            {
                using (var isoStream = isf.OpenFile(name_file_audio, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    **mediaSound**.Stop();
                    **mediaSound**.SetSource(isoStream);

                    **mediaSound**.Position = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                    **mediaSound**.Volume = 20;
                    **mediaSound**.Play();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

the problem is the **mediasound**.. nothing appears when i try to import the references.. anyone can tell how can i do that? i think the method is correct but i can't test it because the error..

**RESOLVED**

Here's the solution:

-> [Incorrect value in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135381/incorrect-value-in-string)

Comment: You should post your solution so it can be useful to others in the future.

Comment: It's OK to answer your own questions.  Remember that one purpose of StackOverflow is to build a good repository of coding problems and answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect value in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135381/incorrect-value-in-string)